# Stupid js func undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm writing a Chrome extension, in my background.html page, it is injecting a js file with this command:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "mod.js"});
```

All of the code from this file is running on the page just fine, except for one function not being defined for an `onclick` property.

I am changing the `innerHTML` of Facebook's main page, the div that contains "top news" and "most recent"

I'm inserting this html:

```
"<a href='#' onclick='thisIsUndefined()'>
  <span class='someClass'>
    Better feed
  </span>
</a>"
```

And right in the js file that is injected, `thisIsUndefined` is perfectly stated as:

```
function thisIsUndefined () {
    alert("is it working yet?");
}
```

I even have another function in the file that I am using, but whenever I click the link that's inserted, the I get an error saying that it's undefined.

Exact error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: thisIsUndefined is not defined

Here's the whole file for reference:

http://texthmu.com/Devin/HMU%20ext/mod.js

Could you recommend any keywords like 'global' or 'var' that *could* fix the definition?

Comment: Is the function stupid?

Comment: Oh, it absolutely _was_ at the time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I found:

```
$("#elementID").click(function() {
    myFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Scripts on the page and content scripts are isolated. They interact with the same DOM, but not directly with each other's variables. When you add `onclick`, it's going to look for that function in the site's scripts. The best way to do it would be to use `document.createElement` and then use `onclick` or `addEventListener` to attach your function. If you want to go the `innerHTML` route, append it to the DOM first, then find it and attach your event.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjYpQ/

Comment: That's exactly it! Very sharp!

Answer (score 2):

You're a bit out of luck on that one due to Chrome's execution model:

> Content scripts execute in a special
> environment called an isolated world.
> They have access to the DOM of the
> page they are injected into, but not
> to any JavaScript variables or
> functions created by the page. It
> looks to each content script as if
> there is no other JavaScript executing
> on the page it is running on. The same
> is true in reverse: **JavaScript running
> on the page cannot call any functions
> or access any variables defined by
> content scripts.**

(emphasis in bold)

Source: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment